# Calling the constructor varibles

Tags: this

How can I access the constructor variables in c?

For example in java there is init, and later in the code I can call it by saying "this. "
Is there any equivalent of this in c?

Comment: C by default has no such thing like a class system. This is a feature of languages that implement class or prototype based object orientation, in general.

Comment: What do you mean by a constructor in C?

Comment: As an entry point, you can have `int main`, but you don't have an equivalence for `this` to retain the context.